# Spring data rest repository keyword OR

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have an object with an attribute that contains an OR in the name. 
Or is also a keyword in spring data rest that is used to concatenate property expressions in repositories.

I have an object called Instance with an attribute instanceOrUrlId.

I want to be able to query an instance by searching with this attribute.
Normally I would just put:
findInstanceByInstanceOrUrlId.

What would i do to specify that the OR is in the property and is not being used to combine properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you dont use JPQL Query with spring data repositories as follow:

```
@Query("SELECT messageEntity FROM StandardMessageEntity messageEntity " +
        " WHERE messageEntity.standardMessageKey.messageType = :instanceOrUrlId" +
        " AND messageEntity.activeMessage = true")
List<StandardMessageEntity> findInstanceByInstanceOrUrlId(@Param("instanceOrUrlId") String instanceOrUrlId);
```

Above is just and example, just create a method and use `@Query` to define a jpql query, that will work. Use the name of the method that you want, and just create select using the property you want, use `@Param` to set the named parameter on it, you could receive a `List<Entity>` or `Entity`, as you want.